# saving dynamic textfield value on click of button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

There is CustomCell in tableviewcontroller .And in which there is dynamic txtfield. which is viewed by tag value. I am saving textfield value on dictionary on "textFieldShouldEndEditing". I want to save textfield value on button (Textfied is dynamic,no outlet is created for textfield).
[First Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpUlo.png)

I want to edit the saved address. [Second Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwQEO.png)

kindly revert asap

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question properly then,

You need to set the button (Which i guess is also inside the custom cell), same tag as that of the indexpath of the cell. 
By that you can get the indexPath of the cell and get the cell by 
`MyCustomCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:button.tag]`

Then, you can get the textfield inside the cell also by just calling `cell.textFieldName.text`, and you will get the text.

For more clarity the IBAction method of the button, should be something like this.

```
 -(IBAction)buttonClickedToSaveTexd:(id)sender{

      UIButton *btnOfCertainCell = (UIButton*)sender;
      MyCustomCellClass *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:btnOfCertainCell.tag];
      NSString *textOfTheCell = currentCell.textFieldName.text;
 }
```

Again, for this to work, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to assign the button tag as `indexPath.row`. You dont need to set tag of the textfield.

Comment: i don't want to create new class.i want to edit my saved address,so how tell me how to do that?

Comment: I thought you mentioned you have a custom `UITableviewCell`. So its natural you would also have a custom cell class.

Comment: did u saw attached image.m saving textfield value on textFieldShouldEndEditing.and m its custom cell, so m viewing it by tag.

Comment: Your query is very unclear, What have you tried? what is it exactly you want.

Comment: sir firstly refer attached image.n secondly i have created a customcell so i have not created any outlet for textfield,m taking textfield by tag value
 UITextField *textFldName=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1100]; UITextField *textFldaddress=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1101]; UITextField *textFldpincode=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1102]; UITextField *textFldstate=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1103]; UITextField *textFldcity=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1104];UITextField *textFldPhone=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1105];

Comment: and m saving value of textfield in dictionary on textFieldShouldEndEditing.

Comment: You want to save the value of the textfield on Button click also right?
Please edit your question with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and its content.

Comment: n i want to edit my saved address(the image is provided in question).so the dictionary will update only when i will click all the field.so how to handle it

Comment: The images are not clearing up the question, You need to post some code as to what have you tried till now, untill you do we wont be able to help you